# Accessing Certificate from within a C# Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, azure-functions

I need to access a certificate from my Azure Function.

I followed the steps outlined in [Runtime error loading certificate in Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240195/runtime-error-loading-certificate-in-azure-functions/40247512#40247512) but it didn't work out.

```
private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string thumbprint, TraceWriter log)
{
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    try
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        log.Info("Enumerating certificates");
        foreach (var cert in store.Certificates) {
            log.Info(cert.Subject);
        }
        var col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
        if (col == null || col.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return col[0];
    }
    finally
    {
        store.Close();
    }
```

}

Two certificates where uploaded to the Azure Function and the setting WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES was added as well and set to either * or to the thumpbrint of the required certificate, but to no avail.

The GetCertificate method should print a list of all certificates in the store, but the store is empty.

Any clues on how to solve this?

Comment: did you try searching for a similar problem for webjobs? since the solution would be identical

Comment: Yes. They all suggest that the approach outlined in the link above should work. But it doesn't.

Comment: I always use StoreLocation.LocalMachine when I access a cert in azure. I haven't tried in Functions but in other WebApps and CloudService it works with that LocalMachine

Comment: LocalMachine does have a few certificates, however not those I uploaded via the Azure Portal.

Comment: Okey... I tried and had the same problem. Then tried again, but this time I created the function selecting App Service Plan and not Hosting Plan... and also made sure that when I copy paste the Thumbprint to settings I checked that there are no extra non-printable chars added and I got your code just working!!! Try following the steps and let me know if you succeed!

Comment: Indeed, if I switch to the AppService Plan, I get the certificates. Seems, It's not supported in the other hosting scenario. How unfortunate.

Comment: Created an issue on github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1032

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE:
Client certificates are now supported in the **Consumption** plan.

Client certificates are not yet supported in our **Consumption** plan, only in **App Service** plan. This is tracked by an issue in our repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/538). We're working on it - please follow that issue for status. Thanks.

Comment: it seems that it can be done now via Azure Keyvault, uploading a certificate in the Function App and then retrieving the content via a secret in the function

Comment: It should now be supported in both Consumption and App Service plans. I think the answer should be updated to reflect that.

Comment: It works now on consumption plan and also app service and here is my full answer on how to deal with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778977/how-to-manage-signed-certificates-with-azure-function-v2/53780469#53780469

Comment: How to find the certificate on LINUX consumption plans?