# How to manage signed certificates with Azure Function V2

Tags: azure, ssl, certificate, azure-functions

I am working on Azure Functions App on Consumption Plan. The Func App required to load a specific signed certificate.

In local machine I setup the certificate as personal certificate and everything works fine.

After publishing on azure, I am getting this error:

> There are 0 certificates with the subject name cert.name in LocalMachine, MyUse scripts/certificates/ to generate this

Nothing helpful on SO or even in Azure Func documentation on how to use certificate with azure functions.

Anyone has experience with that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it and it's pretty straight forward.

First go to platform features under your Function App and you should find SSL as shown below.

[image]

Then you can add a public, private or SSL certificate based on your needs. In my case I want to add a private Certificate which i already exported and have it's private key.

[image]

After uploading your certificate, go to your app settings and add this key/value:

> WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES: "Your Cert Thumbprint"

You should be able to load the certificate using this Thumbprint like this:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

    ...
    X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                                X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                // Replace below with your certificate's thumbprint
                                "000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                                false);
    // Get the first cert with the thumbprint
    if (certCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection[0];
        // Use certificate
        Console.WriteLine(cert.FriendlyName);
    }
    certStore.Close();
    ...
```

Comment: how do you test it locally?

Comment: If someone has the same doubt as @Bhavesh, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/self-signed-certificates-guide#create-a-self-signed-certificate