# Unable to access private keycertificate from Azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to call a REST API from azure function app which requires a client certificate.
I followed this [How to manage signed certificates with Azure Function V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778977/how-to-manage-signed-certificates-with-azure-function-v2/53780469#53780469) and did below steps:-

1)I have uploaded my private key certificate(.PFX) in TLS/SSL settings under private key certificate.

2)Added a key under configuration/application settings for

**WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES: "My Cert Thumbprint"**

Then I tried to access the certificate in my code using this

using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

```
...
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                            X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                            // Replace below with your certificate's thumbprint
                            "000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                            false);
// Get the first cert with the thumbprint
if (certCollection.Count > 0)
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection[0];
    // Use certificate
    Console.WriteLine(cert.FriendlyName);
}
certStore.Close();
...
```

I don't get back any certificate. What am I doing wrong?
If I upload a public certificate(.cer), I am able to access the certificate but it doesn't have the private key so I am unable to call the service.

Answer (score 1):

First, please check if you have copy the `Thumbprint`(in below screenshot) to your function application settings `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES`.
[image]

Then please test with some other fields of `cert` in your code because sometimes the certificate doesn't have `FriendlyName`. I test in my side and it shows nothing for `FriendlyName`. Then I test with `Issuer`, it works fine.(**Notice** I use `log.LogInformation(cert.Issuer);` instead of `Console.WriteLine(cert.Issuer);` because I find `Console.WriteLine` shows nothing)
[image]

Comment: I am getting the certificate count as zero if I upload a .pfx file. The issue is not with logging. I am able to get a certificate if I upload a .cer file.

Comment: Hi @user911 I test it in my side and found if I upload a `.cer` certificate, I can get the certificate in function even if I did not set `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` with `Thumbprint` in application settings (if I use hard code `Thumbprint` in my function code). But if I upload a `.pfx` certificate, it is necessary to set `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` with `Thumbprint` in application settings even if I use hard code `Thumbprint` in my function code. So please check if you have set `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` correctly even if you use hard code `Thumbprint` in your function.

Comment: @user911 If still same problem, please change with another `.pfx` certificate for test.