# App Service - out of disk space when creating a X509 cert from byte[]

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, azure-appservice

c# runs X509Certificate2 constructor using byte array and gets error : **There is not enough space on the disk.**

This article suggests that the private key folder has too many files : [X509Certificate2 Constructor Throwing There is not enough space on the disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53617491/x509certificate2-constructor-throwing-there-is-not-enough-space-on-the-disk)

Short term , can I mitigate in Kudo by clearing out from d:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\machinekeys  ? I got a 404 when I tried to delete one file.
Thanks, Peter

Comment: How many are there?  Do you need them?  How much space do they take up?

Comment: I can see alot. Can I safely delete them ?   I tried manually to delete one and got a 404 not found.